# «Старик как клещами обхватил его...» Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

*Старик **как клещами** обхватил его левой рукой за шею, и Рэдрик, не в силах выпрямиться, на четвереньках поволок его через дыру в ограде, хватаясь руками за мокрую траву.*
Аркадий и Борис Стругацкие. [Пикник на обочине](http://strugacki.ru/book_2/72.html)

Почему "как клещами" не обособляется запятыми?

Comment: Этот оборот точно сравнительный. Изредка встречаются случаи необособления именно между подлежащим и глаголом-сказуемым. Паузы в таких случаях вообще не звучат (в отличие от других позиций), так как они разрывают тесную интонационную связь между подлежащим и сказуемым. Соответственно, и запятые авторы решили не ставить.

Answer (score 1):

*Старик **как клещАми** обхватил его левой рукой за шею, и Рэдрик, не в силах выпрямиться, на четвереньках поволок его через дыру в огрАде, хватаясь руками за мокрую травУ.*

Обособлять сравнительный оборот надо по правилам. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

Розенталь говорит нам, что оба варианта возможны (оборот обособляется, если  он обозначает уподобление, и не обособляется, если на первый план выступает значение обстоятельства образа действия). Также он говорит о том, что   надо учитывать влияние многих факторов, в том числе художественные задачи,стоящие перед автором.

**Что мне показалось важным при решении этой задачи?** Важно то, что это сложная синтаксическая конструкция: сложносочиненное предложение, причем во втором предложении два обособленных оборота, так что получают 4 фонетические фразы.

И всё это надо прочитать, выразив причинно-следственную связь между двумя ситуациями. Вот такая художественная задача стояла перед автором.

Поэтому **не было  здесь возможности обособить ещё и сравнительный оборот**, соответственно он является обстоятельством образа действия со значением "***очень крепко*** обхватил его".

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь:
Сравнительный оборот с союзом *как* не выделяется запятыми, если он входит в сказуемое (образует именную часть составного сказуемого) или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота):
*Я за ними как за детьми хожу.* || Похожий пример (между подлежащим и глаголом).
*Он говорил о привычных вещах как о чём-то необычайно интересном.

Я смотрел как очарованный.

Как ребёнок душою я стал.

Как солнышко она.

Он сидел как громом поражённый.

Этот звук был как звонок будильника.

В баснях звери ведут себя как люди.

Вы эту рыбу разварите, и она сделается как масло; высушите, и сделается как камень.*
Много других примеров: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147,4 (пункт 4.4)

В таких случаях оборот тесно примыкает к глаголу-сказуемому, и паузы вокруг него совсем не звучат. "*Как клещами обхватил*" — именно такой случай. И ещё играет роль то, что сравнение происходит с глаголом, а оборот расположен до него. То есть в момент сравнения ещё не было слова, которое сравнивается. Естественным для сравнения является обратный порядок. Поэтому паузы там и не звучат.

Но в постпозиции уже нет такой связи, и запятая нужна:
*Старик обхватил его левой рукой за шею, как клещами.*

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю, авторы (или редактор) сочли этот случай обстоятельством образа действия.

Такие обстоятельства не всегда можно отличить от сравнительных оборотов, обособление зависит от авторской трактовки. Здесь как раз пограничный, или вернее сказать -  смешанный, случай, когда имеются характерные признаки и сравнения, и образа действия. Так, с одной стороны, творительный падеж довольно явно свидетельствует в пользу трактовки "образ действия".  С другой - не очень получается замена на наречие ("по-клещиному"?).  В таких ситуациях последнее слово - за автором. Видимо, у Стугацких решающим оказалось то обстоятельство, что с учетом контекста главным в подобном уподоблении является результат, а не способ. "Как клещами" здесь - прочно, надежно, а не подобно тому способу, как держат клещи.

Беглый анализ показал, что единства у авторов тут нет. Похожие случаи с "обхватить(,) как клещами", "держать(,) как клещами" часто встречаются и с обособлением. 
При этом мотивов, иных, чем авторское понимание, для выбора решения не просматривается.

> Что мне было говорить, ежели я и правда по воробьям не палил и в чужих
>   загородах шастать у меня моды не было. Ну, а батюшка взял меня за ухо,
>   сдавил, как клещами, да и давай вывинчивать ухо-то. А сам ласково
>   эдак, тихо приговаривает: «Не ври, чадо, перед господом богом, бо не
>   простит господь неправды и тайности, не ври, не ври, не ври…» Я из
>   церкви-то с ревом: ухо как в огне горит, да всего обиднее, что зря.
>   [Василий Белов. Плотницкие рассказы (1968)]
>
> Расшиперил руки-то,  — не овцу имаешь. Он прыгнул вперед и, как
>   клещами, сдавил ее горячее, упругое тело. Она охнула, вырвалась: — 
>   Дурак, нашел с кем играть. [Федор Абрамов. Две зимы и три лета (1968)]
>
> Или нет! Взять бы сейчас промеж пальцев длинный Пашкин нос, сжать бы
>   его, как клещами, и набок повернуть. ― Я вам это припомню, ― сказал
>   Фомич и выбежал из клуба. На улице темь ― глаз коли. [Борис Можаев.
>   Живой (1964-1965)]

Но встречаются и тексты без обособления.

> Она к нему ― плечо в плечо, волосы к щеке ― самые, самые кончики, два
>   волосика, три… Боков как клещами ее охватил, будто в озеро вниз
>   головою кинулся, красноватые большие руки на черном платье резкими
>   пятнами… ― Ах, что вы, что вы, ― встрепенулась Ниночка, ― не надо… ―
>   Все отдам. [А. С. Яковлев. Повольники (1922)]
>
> Я держала мамину жесткую руку, точно через нее крепила единство со
>   всеми родными, далекими предками, со всем своим родом, всеми теми,
>   кто, сцепившись руками, не даст моей дочери уйти. Темная рука моей
>   мамы была их рукою, силы ее были невелики, но за нею стояли наши
>   ушедшие в землю родные, поэтому я как клещами сомкнула пальцы на ее
>   запястье и не давала себе забыться сном, чтобы моя дочь не ускользнула
>   в яму этого сна, я должна была бодрствовать и во имя всех поколений
>   держать ее жизнь в руке. Темнота вибрировала под моими веками, и по
>   ней пробегали сиреневые искры, и я снова раскрывала глаза, цепко держа
>   жизнь моей дочери на привязи. Еще вчера вечером она просто чувствовала
>   недомогание, хныкала, поскрипывала, чмокала губами, требуя соску,
>   ночью нас забрала «скорая», но некому было помочь: шла ночь с субботы
>   на воскресенье, и на шесть отделений дежурил один измученный врач.
>   [Ирина Полянская. Мама (1996)]

Я выбрал случаи, показавшиеся мне наиболее близкими по смыслу к тому, что у Стругацких. Обособление все-таки встречается чаще.

Что же касается объяснения через тесную связь со сказуемым, то она не слишком аргументирована (изъятие оборота не превращает фразу в бессмысленную и/или грамматически неполноценную) и не объясняет случаи иного оформления у авторитетных авторов.

Comment: Розенталь отмечает, что "обычно... сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота", но не всегда. В нашем примере этому способствует позиция. Многие авторы боятся отступать от стандартных норм пунктуации, чтобы не воспринимали как ошибку. А некоторые действуют по чутью, тем самым формируя новые пунктуационные закономерности. Обстоятельство образа действия здесь не сильно получается. Замена должна быть на творительный без "как": *старик клещами обхватил*.

Comment: @oleedd Что мне с этим прикажете делать? Если вы так понимаете Розенталя - ваше право, спорить с вами я не намерен, хотя полагаю, что вы опять привносите отсебятину. Но уж к моему ответу это ваше послание отношения точно не имеет. Я не ставил вопрос так, что безболезненное для смысла изъятие оборота - **единственный** признак отсутвия тесной связи оборота со сказуемым.